# combine several whiles to a foreach in RUBY

Tags: ruby, loops, foreach, while-loop, each

My code looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
Shas = ["Pesachim","Shekalim","Yoma"]
Pesachim=["2a", "2b", "3a", "3b", "4a", "4b", "5a", "5b", "6a", "6b", "7a", "7b"]
Shekalim=["2a", "2b", "3a", "3b", "4a", "4b", "5a", "5b", "6a", "6b", "7a"]
Yoma=["2a", "2b", "3a", "3b", "4a", "4b", "5a", "5b", "6a", "6b", "7a", "7b", "8a", "8b",     "9a", "9b", "10a", "10b", "11a", "11b", "12a", "12b", "13a", "13b", "14a"]

counter = 0
while counter < Pesachim.length
  puts Shas[0] +" "+ Pesachim[counter]
  counter +=1

  bounter = 0
  while bounter < Shekalim.length
    puts Shas[1] +" "+ Shekalim[bounter]
    bounter +=1
```

Can you help me rewrite this as

```
Shas.each do |book|
  counter = 0
  while counter < book.length
    puts book+" "+book[counter]
    counter+=1
  end
```

I think there is some problem with the "books" not being the same as the arrays without double quotes.

Comment: You're missing some `end`s

Comment: Your code examples are invalid. We have to be able to load and run a minimal sample at least, and have a sample data file to load. Because your code is missing `end` statements, we can't guess what else you're doing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the relevance of `Yoma` in your code.

`self.class` is necessary in `main` context. Within a different context, remove it.

```
Shas.first(2).each{|book| self.class.const_get(book).each{|e| puts "#{book} #{e}"}}
```

If you intended to iterate over `Yoma` as well, then:

```
Shas.each{|book| self.class.const_get(book).each{|e| puts "#{book} #{e}"}}
```

Comment: I copied the javascript from somewhere `var arrPesachim,arrShekalim,arrYoma,arrSukah,arrBeitzah,arrRoshHashanah,arrTaanis,arrMegilah,arrMoedKatan,arrChagigah,arrYevamos,arrKesuvos,arrNedarim,arrNazir,arrSotah,arrGitin,arrKidushin,arrBavaKama,arrBavaMetzia,arrBavaBasra,arrSanhedrin,arrMakos,arrShevuos,arrAvodahZarah,arrHorayos,arrZevachim,arrMenachos,arrChulin,arrBechoros,arrErchin,arrTemurah,arrKerisus,arrMeilah,arrNidah, ArrDummy`

Comment: I guess Yoma meant that I was repeating some code and thought that I could make another loop from the list of arrays to do that typing for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want is a hash:

```
Shas = {Pesachim: ["2a", "2b", "3a", "3b", "4a", "4b", "5a", "5b", "6a", "6b", "7a", "7b"],
        Shekalim: ["2a", "2b", "3a", "3b", "4a", "4b", "5a", "5b", "6a", "6b", "7a"],
        Yoma: ["2a", "2b", "3a", "3b", "4a", "4b", "5a", "5b", "6a", "6b", "7a", "7b", "8a", "8b", "9a", "9b", "10a", "10b", "11a", "11b", "12a", "12b", "13a", "13b", "14a"]}
```

Then you can use the .each method like so:

```
Shas.each do |key, values|
  values.each {|counter| puts "#{key} #{counter}"}
end
```

Comment: exactly, I've got all those #s copied, I don't mind changing the outside to (list) [array] or {hash} if you could just remind me how to iterate across the data efficiently.  I kind of think it's a 2-d array myself, but no you've convinced me it's a hash.